# ASP.NET Gridview appends to itself upon SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to build a Gridview which allows me to select a row and then (eventually) do something with that row. The problem is, every time I select a new row, the Gridview appends to itself. So, for example, when it first comes up, everything is fine (e.g., 5 rows appear). When I select a row, though, it is redrawn and now has 10 rows. When I select another row it grows to 15 rows, etc.

Here is what I think is the pertinent code. Please let me know if you need more in order to help me prevent the Gridview from appending to itself.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lname" HeaderText="Last Name" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Lname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fname" HeaderText="First Name" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Fname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportedDt" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date Report Taken" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="ReportedDt" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IncidentDt" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Incident Date" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="IncidentDt" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Disciplinary Action Taken" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Category" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Manager" HeaderText="Manager" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Manager" />
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30"  />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Details"  OnClick="lnkEdit_Click" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And here are the pertinent methods in the code behind.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        string sql = null;
        string connetionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=calgon;Integrated Security=true";
        sql = "select Category, EnteredBy, Type, Fname, Mname, Lname, IncidentDt, ReportedDt, Title, Manager, " +
            "Shift, Events, Steps, Resources, Consequences from Form where IsVoid = 0";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        adapter.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='aquamarine';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='white';";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click last column for selecting this row.";
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
        //string pName = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        //msg.Text = "<b>Publisher Name  &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;   " + pName + "</b>";
    }
```

Every time I click Select on one of the rows, the append occurs. What's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Tested your snippet and it works as it should. No extra rows are appended after a PostBack

Comment: I realize you can't fix the problem if you can't reproduce it. Perhaps it's a browser issue? I'm using Chrome.